# How to increase font size of autocomplete widget in processing-ide?

Tags: processing-ide

I have increased my font-size in processing IDE, but when autocomplete suggestion shows up , the font size is a bit small and I don't find a way to increase it.

Any setting I can change to make autocomplete font larger ?

[image: tiny font for autocomplete]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, based on [the source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/a6e0e227a948e7e2dc042c04504d6f5b8cf0c1a6/java/src/processing/mode/java/pdex/CompletionPanel.java#L152) the code completion list has each item's font hardcoded to sans size 12 at the moment:

```
setFont(Toolkit.getSansFont(12, Font.PLAIN));
```

Currently there is no option in the Processing Preferences panel to change the
code completion text font size.

You could request this as a feature and hope it will be implemented at some point.

If you need this urgently you might need to clone the repo, implement the change yourself and recompile the editor: bonus points if you open a pull request so it becomes a permanent feature! :

Another pragmatic option might be to use a different editor other than the Processing IDE. (This can be a Java IDE such as Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ/etc. or an editor such as SublimeText/VSCode/Atom etc. in conjuction with the `processing-java` command line utility. Some of these editors might already have community contributed plugins)

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted after waiting for a few more days, thanks